# TransactionScope; how to commit after an exception occured

Tags: sql-server, exception, transactionscope

I am retrofitting a somewhat complex program. There are hundreds of UI's which may use reflection to invoke lists of methods. Some methods call essentially 3rd party DLL's. Some DLL's throw exceptions.

There is 1 DLL that throws an exception apparently just to say I'm done. From a database viewpoint this exception can safely be ignored; however I can't seem to get transactionscope to ignore it. Or I'm ignorant of some transactionscope environment behavoir.

The logic thus far

using transactionscope required

```
for each item in the methods list..
  ... lots of code hitting databases.. that works

  one of the methods..
      using transactionscope suppress 

         try
             dagnamit.dll
         catch exception  -- this exception I want transactionscope to ignore
         end try

         transactionscope Completed
     end using

... more code .. that works when dagnamit.dll isn't called
                 but fails when called, reporting can't call a "disposed object: Transaction:

transactionscope Completed
```

end using

timeout is not an issue. yes, multiple servers involved. Naturally I don't have access to the DLL source.

Comment: Why would you want to commit the transaction if there was an exception? Surely that means that the data is not consistent?

Comment: What does `using transactionscope suppress` mean? Are you creating a new `TransactionScope` here?